# One HDMI/USB cable for mouse, keyboard and display?

Tags: usb, hdmi, vga, kvm-switch

I have a KVM which has only VGA for input. It came with cables which have VGA male on the KVM side and then VGA male and USB on the computer side, which allows me to connect my mouse and keyboard directly to the KVM.

Neither of my computers have a VGA port, they both have some USB ports and HDMI ports and one has two displayports. I want a way to connect each computer to the KVM with just one cable and have that connect both the display and the mouse and keyboard. I was looking for a cable like mine just with HDMI and USB on the computer side and I can't seem to find one, I'm guessing they don't exist?

Neither computer really has any other useful ports by the way, and I'm pretty sure that the one without displayport only has USB 2.0.

Comment: *"I want a way to connect each computer to the KVM with just one cable"* -- Even if you had a KVM *switch* with HDMI ports instead of VGA, you would not be able to switch devices with *"just one cable"*.  That KVM switch is using a non-standard cable and unused pins of the VGA HD15 connector.  *"I was looking for a cable like mine just with HDMI and USB on the computer side"* -- You cannot plug HDMI into VGA without an active converter.  The cable you are looking for does not exist.  You need to look for a new KVM switch for HDMI.  If your display is VGA, then you will need a converter

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I'll probably used the supplied cable with a converter on my computer's side. I tried it today and it seemed to work fine. I didn't realise the KVM cables were non-standard, but it explains a lot! I'll keep this VGA KVM only because it was cheap and I already have it.